# Using TunTap with linux kernel 2.6

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, tunnel, tun

The TunTap documentation [on the vtun site](http://vtun.sourceforge.net/tun/faq.html#1.3) points out that the driver is only supported till Linux kernel 2.4. Is there any way to get it to run on 2.6 and 3.2 versions of Linux?

A cat on the device shows:

```
# cat /dev/net/tun
 cat: File descriptor in bad state
```

I tried installing directly from the rpm file to see how far I could go and got:

```
# rpm -i tun-1.1-6.rh71.i386.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
     /bin/sh is needed by tun-1.1-6.i386
```

Is there any way I can get this to work on linux 2.6+ or are there any good alternatives to tuntap that you are aware of?

Comment: That FAQ is out of date. Linux 2.6 (and 3.x) comes with a tun/tap driver. You can create tuntap devices with e.g. the `ip tuntap add` command. Documentation is as per usual scarce/non-existing though, perhaps [this](http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/) could be of help

Comment: I have the /dev/net/tun but a cat on the file says "cat: /dev/net/tun: File descriptor in bad state".

ip tuntap add says "Object "tuntap" is unknown"

Comment: I read somewhere that ip command is outdated on some versions and I have to use tunctl. Let me try that and get back to you.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to read (using cat) /dev/net/tun anyway, at least not without configuring the device by ioctl's first. What are you actually trying to do ?

Comment: I got it to work by using tunctl instead of ip tuntap add.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

The tuntap documentation is outdated. Also, in newer versions of linux, you might need to use

```
tunctl
```

instead of

```
ip tuntap add
```

To install tunctl on debian Squeeze, install the package 'uml-utilities' which provides the tunctl command. You can add a new tunnel using

```
tunctl -t tun1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below script to create it automatically, just copy the contents in to a file.sh, change the "ETHOIPADDR" to your ip address, similarly also the change the gateway and broadcast address and run the script with sudo permission.

```
#!/bin/sh 
# 
# script to bring up the tun device in QEMU in bridged mode 
# first parameter is name of tap device (e.g. tap0)
#
# some constants specific to the local host - change to suit your host
#
ETH0IPADDR=192.168.0.3
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
BROADCAST=192.168.0.255
#
# First take eth0 down, then bring it up with IP address 0.0.0.0 
#
/sbin/ifdown eth0
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 promisc up
#
# Bring up the tap device (name specified as first argument, by QEMU)
#
/usr/sbin/openvpn --mktun --dev $1 --user `id -un`
/sbin/ifconfig $1 0.0.0.0 promisc up
#
# create the bridge between eth0 and the tap device
#
/usr/sbin/brctl addbr br0
/usr/sbin/brctl addif br0 eth0
/usr/sbin/brctl addif br0 $1
# 
# only a single bridge so loops are not possible, turn off spanning tree protocol
#
/usr/sbin/brctl stp br0 off 
# 
# Bring up the bridge with ETH0IPADDR and add the default route 
#
/sbin/ifconfig br0 $ETH0IPADDR netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast $BROADCAST
/sbin/route add default gw $GATEWAY
#
# stop firewall - comment this out if you don't use Firestarter
#
/sbin/service firestarter stop
```